# How to run test multiple times with different path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I have the same functionality available on multiple show pages for different object. They have exactly the same behavior - I render it as a partial and pass current object to it, as follows:

```
<%= render "tags", object: @customer, url: customer_path(@customer) %>
```

I want to implement a shared test for it - do not want to implement it several times  for different object.

When test fails, i would like to know on which page (for which object) it happened.

I use minitest + capybara.

I can have one test and run it multiple times as be:

I would like to have something like this:

```
setup do
 @customer = create(:customer)
 @lead = create(:lead)
end

@objects = ['customer', 'lead']

@objects.each do |o|
 test "#{o.class.name}: test sth" do
   path = # --> customer_path(@customer), lead_path(@lead), etc....
   visit path
    ......
    ......
 end
end
```

How to generate for each iteration correct path and use correct object (@customer, @lead, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. See my solution below:

```
require "application_system_test_case"


class TagTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
   setup do
     @user = users(:operator)
     sign_in(@user)
   end


   [:customer, :lead].each do |tested_object|
     define_method("test_#{tested_object}") do
       object = create(tested_object)
       visit eval("#{tested_object}_path(object)")
       .....
       .....
     end
   end
end
```